# How to prevent html5 video player play icon from disappearing in iPhone Safari

Tags: javascript, jquery, ios, html, html5-video

I have a basic video player in Safari and after few scrolls, the play button on the video screen gets lost like in the picture.

```
<video controls poster="/images/w3html5.gif">
  <source src="movie.mp4" type="video/mp4">
  <source src="movie.ogg" type="video/ogg">
  Your browser does not support the video tag.
</video>
```

[image]

Any help would be appreciated.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: After a few seconds while playing?

Comment: @m02ph3u5 no It happens before I played the video. The page loads and I scroll down without taping to video

Comment: I have exact problem on iphone the play icon disappears after few seconds but on ipad i don't have this problem. Did you find any solution for it ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's a webkit [bug](https://bugs.webkit.org/show_bug.cgi?id=158146) and has been fixed in iOS 10. There is a simple workaround:

```
video::-webkit-media-controls-start-playback-glyph {
    will-change: opacity;
}
```

Refer: https://www.mail-archive.com/webkit-changes@lists.webkit.org/msg101173.html#trunkSourceWebCoreModulesmediacontrolsmediaControlsiOScss